Blessed npm styling list item rows conditionally
I am using the Blessed npm package to render markdown in the terminal and I want to render tags different colours.
For example:
h1 = yellow
p = green
...
I have tried a few different methods but have had no luck. For example:
list.on("element", function (item) {
  item.style.fg = "red";
});

Can anyone out there point me in the right direction?
Full function:
function createList(markdown) {
  const list = blessed.list({
    items: markdown.split("\n"),
    height: "75%",
    width: "75%",
    scrollable: true,
    style: {
      selected: {
        fg: "black",
        bg: "yellow",
      },
    },
    border: {
      type: "line",
    },
    mouse: true,
    keys: true,
    vi: true,
    alwaysScroll: true,
    scrollbar: {
      ch: " ",
      inverse: true,
    },
    left: "center",
    top: "center",
  });
  list.on("element", function (item) {
      item.style.fg = "red"; // Change the foreground color to red
  });
  return list;
}

